# Falcor: How to define a function in falcor's JSON Graph?

Tags: falcor

I'm very interested in this Modal Layer Library --- Falcor. And I read the official document of Falcor, and in [JSON Graph section](http://netflix.github.io/falcor/documentation/jsongraph.html), a topic of **The Abstract JSON Graph Operations**, and when it is talking about `call` operation, I'm totally confused. Here is my code according the official example:

```js
var jsonGraphObject = {
    todosById: {
        "44": {
            name: "get milk from corner store",
            addedAt: 29689724399,
            done: false,
            prerequisites: [{ $type: "ref", value: ["todosById", 54] }]
        },
        "54": {
            name: "withdraw money from ATM",
            addedAt: 15687384689,
            done: false,
            prerequisites: []
        }
    },
    todos: [
        { $type: "ref", value: ["todosById", 44] },
        { $type: "ref", value: ["todosById", 54] }
    ]
};
var model = new falcor.Model({
  cache: jsonGraphObject
});
```

Then the document showed me about how to use `call`:

```js
model.call(
    // callPath
    ["todos", "add"],
    // arguments
    ["pick up car from the shop"], 
    // refPaths
    [
        ["addedAt"]
    ],
    // thisPaths
    [
        ["length"]
    ])
    .then(console.log.bind(console))
```

And the document just show me the result, but my code did not work, I totally do not know where is this `add` function, and I don't know how to define a function in Falcor's JSON Graph.

I googled about it, but haven't get my answer.So is there any example or boilerplate project there? Thanks.

Comment: found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37926068/i-need-falcors-call-method-explained-or-a-good-example and https://github.com/Netflix/falcor/issues/753

Answer (score 1):

Functions are not cached so they cannot be in the `cache` property of the options passed to the `Model` constructor.

`call` will delegate processing to the model's data source, so the consequences depends on the implementation of the data source. If you use an [`HttpDataSource`](http://netflix.github.io/falcor/doc/HttpDataSource.html) that calls a [Router](http://netflix.github.io/falcor/documentation/router.html) on the server-side, then the function resides on the server.