# I need Falcor's `call` method explained; or a good example?

Tags: falcor, falcor-router

**Is there a good detailed explanation or usage example anywhere of Falcor's `call` method?**

I'm struggling to understand Falcor's `call` method. I understand the first to arguments (`functionPath` and `args`), but I'm clueless on what the last two arguments are and how they are used (`refSuffixes` and `thisPaths`). I don't understand their descriptions. From [Falcor's API reference](https://netflix.github.io/falcor/doc/Model.html#call):

```js
/**
 * Invokes a function in the DataSource's JSONGraph object.
 * @name call
 * @function
 * @arg {Path} functionPath the path to the function to invoke
 * @arg {Array.<Object>} args the arguments to pass to the function
 * @arg {Array.<PathSet>} refSuffixes paths to retrieve from the targets of JSONGraph References in the function's response.
 * @arg {Array.<PathSet>} thisPaths paths to retrieve from function's this object after successful function execution
 * @returns {Observable.<JSONGraphEnvelope>} jsonGraphEnvelope the response returned from the server.
 * @memberof DataSource.prototype
 */
```

I haven't been able to find a good usage example either. The best I've found is from [this falcor issue comment](https://github.com/Netflix/falcor/issues/753#issuecomment-195407284) (snippet below), but there are some variable definitions missing - eg. `titleRef`:

```js
var dataSource = new Router([
 {
        route: 'list.push',
        call: function(callPath, args) {

            // retrieving the title id from the reference path:            
            titleId = titleRef.value[1];
            if (parseInt(titleId, 10).toString() !== titleId.toString())
                throw new Error("invalid input");

            return myListService.
                addTitle(titleId).
                then(function(length) {
                    return [
                        {
                            path: ['myList', length - 1],
                            value: titleRef
                        },
                        {
                            path: ['myList', 'length'],
                            value: length
                        }
                    ];
                });
        }
    }
]);
```

In another [client](https://github.com/hgwood/falcorception/blob/master/client/src/node_modules/app/app.js#L39) and [server](https://github.com/hgwood/falcorception/blob/master/server/index.js#L114) example, it shows one way to use the call method: returning an object with `{ paths: [...], jsonGraph: {...} }` — *What is the difference between returning [pathValues](https://netflix.github.io/falcor/doc/global.html#PathValue) or this object with `paths` and `jsonGraph`?*

I seem to be missing something in my local implementations and I'm thinking it's because I don't understand the last two arguments to a falcor `call` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand `thisPaths`, however I'm with you, I don't quite get `refPaths` yet. Here's my understanding of `thisPaths`.

If the call path is `list.push` then we can think of `push` as the method and `list` as the object. In other words, when `list.push()` is called, figuratively speaking, `this === list` inside the `push()` function. This requires some imagination, since it isn't *literally* the case in terms of JS runtime semantics. Rather Falcor is maintaining a loose analogy to JavaScript, if that makes sense.

So then, in client-side code, if you pass `thisPaths` like this:

```
model.call(
  ['list','push'], // call path
  [...], // args
  [...], // refPaths
  [['length'],[0, 'foo']] // thisPaths
)
```

...it will concatenate the `this` object with those `thisPaths`, and the resulting paths will be automatically refreshed in the model cache when the response happens:

```
[['list', 'length'], ['list', 0, 'foo']]
```

That's nice since it gives the client some control over what gets updated as a result of a call operation, without resorting to manual cache invalidations and re-fetches, and without the implementor of the call route handler needing to anticipate in advance what clients want.

Specifically, all of that happens without the implementor of the `call` handler function needing to do anything. (That's what had thrown me for a loop at first.) It's just a convenience that's available to you on the client side, and is automatically built into Falcor.

Comment: So would you say that if I have a route `postsById[{keys:postIds}][{keys:fields}]`, I would want to name my call path to be something like `postsById.update` so I can utilize `thisPaths` to run paths through my first route?

Comment: I think I follow, and I think yes. Personally, if I had a call operation that updated a post, I'd probably have the call path be something like `postsById[{keys:postIds}].update`; i.e. the post ID would be part of the call path. That way, I wouldn't need to supply the ID as an argument, nor would I need to prepend the ID to `thisPaths`. And it seems more "Falcorish" that `this` would be the thingById that I'm operating on.

Comment: Oh sweet - thanks - i hadn't even thought of being able to use pathSet stuff in call routes... how would you get those into the call function if you weren't passing them through as arguments?

Comment: The arguments to `call()` are `(pathSet, args)` so you'd want to unpack `pathSet` for that info. It would look something like `['postsById', ['123'], 'update']`.

Comment: I see - thanks. This was enough info to get what I needed.

Comment: `refPaths` is the same except the paths are relative to references found in the response graph of the call instead of `this`. It is useful if the function creates stuff and returns references to the stuff. Then the clients can ask for as much info about the stuff as it wants. Example here: [server](https://github.com/hgwood/falcorception/blob/master/server/index.js#L114), [client](https://github.com/hgwood/falcorception/blob/master/client/src/node_modules/app/app.js#L39). The client asks to create an API and get the `id`, `name` fields from the created API while the server only returns a ref.

Comment: refPaths is still not clear no me @HugoWood on your example you passed   [["id"], ["name"], ["url"]], and I suppose this are relative to {$type: "ref", value: ["apisById", id]}, but what if there was more than one ref?

Comment: @FabioCosta Falcor would resolve the `refPaths` for each of the refs.